# Ocaml Type error: This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type 'c list

Tags: ocaml

I'm required to output a pair of lists and I'm not understanding why the pair I'm returning is not of the correct type.

```
let rec split l = match l with
  | [] -> []
  | [y] -> [y]
  | x :: xs ->
      let rec helper l1 acc = match l1 with
        | [] -> []
        | x :: xs ->
            if ((List.length xs) = ((List.length l) / 2)) then
                (xs, (x :: acc))
            else helper xs (x :: acc)
      in helper l []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please take the time to copy/paste and format your code on SO rather than providing a link to an image. It makes it much easier to help, and more useful in the future.)

The first case of the `match` in your helper function doesn't return a pair. All the cases of a `match` need to return the same type (of course).

Note that the cases of your outermost `match` are also of different types (if you assume that `helper` returns a pair).